# Removing SSIS variables with PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis, devops

I am working on implementing devops pipelines for Microsoft BI projects using SQL Server 2016, primarily using VSTS and PowerShell. For the release process for SSIS, I am using the [integration services assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.aspx) as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-deploy-powershell).

I'm having an issue getting the [Remove method from the assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929870.aspx) to work correctly. I want developers to be able to define variables in an XML file in SSDT and the release PowerShell script to delete a variable if it exists (and the value is different in the XML). It will then be recreated with the new values (there is no alter method on a single variable that I can see).

Here is a code sample which simplifies what I am trying to do:

```
$FolderName = "VariablesTest1"
$EnvironmentName = "Development"

# Load the IntegrationServices Assembly
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices") | Out-Null;

# Store the IntegrationServices Assembly namespace
$ISNamespace = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices"

# Create a connection to the server
$sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $sqlConnectionString

# Create the Integration Services object
$integrationServices = New-Object $ISNamespace".IntegrationServices" $sqlConnection

$catalog = $integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"]
$folder = $integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Folders[$FolderName]

# Creates the folder
$folder = New-Object $ISNamespace".CatalogFolder" ($catalog, $FolderName, "Folder description")
      $folder.Create()

$environment = $folder.Environments[$EnvironmentName]

# Creates the Environment
$environment = New-Object $ISNamespace".EnvironmentInfo" ($folder, $EnvironmentName, "Description")
    $environment.Create()

# Add the variable to the environment
$environment.Variables.Add("Variable2", "String", "MyValue", $false, "This is my variable")
$environment.Alter()

# Print the variable to make sure it exists
Write-Host $environment.Variables.Name

# Delete the variable
$environment.Variables.Remove("Variable2")
```

This will create the required objects in the Integration Services Catalog and should create, then delete the variable but it doesn't. The variable is created but not deleted.

Am I calling the remove method in the wrong place or is it something else?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the additional `$environment.Alter()` after your removal.

Comment: @gvee yep that was exactly it - can't believe it was something so simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the additional $environment.Alter() after your removal!

```
# Delete the variable
$environment.Variables.Remove("Variable2")
$environment.Alter()
```